# How should I interpret the results of linear and non-linear dose-response meta-analysis?

Tags: r, regression, meta-analysis, dose-response

Fellow statisticians!

I am currently doing a project involving dose-response meta-analysis, and I would like to ask how should I interpret my findings.

I have estimated the linear dose-response effect using the Greenland and Longnecker approach in two-stage dose-response meta-analysis, which returned a significant result (RR 1.40 [95% CI: 1.10-1.90]).

Furthermore, I estimated the non-linearity using restricted cubic spline by using three knots (i.e. 10%, 50%, 90%). The model showed non-linearity (p non-linearity=0.0011; assessed with Wald test); however, the estimates were not significant for both doses (p=0.88 for the 2nd knot and p=0.40 for the 3rd knot). I noticed that some published DRMA used AIC to assess the goodness-of-fit between linear and non-linear DRMA, and the AIC of my linear model was lower than the AIC of my non-linear model. However, the Wald test revealed equivocal findings.

How should I interpret these findings?

Thank you very much. Any help will be much appreciated.

Best,